# tortoisehg 2.1.3 context menu clicks do nothing in win7 x86

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm running tortoisehg 2.1.3 (and now 2.1.4) on a win7 x86 system upgraded from 2.1.2.  When I click on the context menus (e.g. workbench) nothing happens.

I enabled shell debugging:  `[HKCU]\Software\TortoiseHg\ value DebugShellExt="1"`

Which yielded: `[THGx86] RunDialog: THG root is empty` in DbgView.

I've manually checked that `\Software\TortoiseHg\ default is "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg"` for both [HKCU] and [HKLM].  Though I'm having some problems where installing TortoiseHg seems to make these registry keys empty and unreadable and I have to manually change ownership on them to even delete them.

Anyone else having problems with these context menus in this version of TortoiseHg on windows?  Anyone know if something has changed in the installer?  Anyone know of something that could cause these registry keys to become inaccessible even to the application that created them?

Comment: Have you considered reporting this problem in the TortoiseHg mailing list?

Comment: Did, no response so far...  actually We got the context menus sort of working, but now the icons still aren't updating properly, I'm thinking both are related to the registry permissions issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issues are resolved in more recent versions of TortoiseHG (2.2.1 and later).  So, I'm marking this question answered.